# Why global.mongoose for caching mongodb connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

Why do add `global.mongoose` for caching mongodb connection?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}
```

What is its purpose? is it the same if I do this?

```
global.cached = global.cached || {conn:null, promise:null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to only create one connection then use it everywhere instead of creating a connection everytime